# IBM watson conversation using facebook chatbot Error Issue

Tags: node.js, facebook, chatbot

Here is the error i face. Im using ibm botkit-middleware. What could be the error and how should it be solve?

```
Fatal TypeError: Cannot read property 'output' of undefined
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\User\Desktop\botkit-middleware-master3\examples\multi-bot\bot-facebook.js:45:32)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\User\Desktop\botkit-middleware-master3\examples\multi-bot\node_modules\botkit\lib\CoreBot.js:753:28)
    at Object.Botkit.botkit.trigger (C:\Users\User\Desktop\botkit-middleware-master3\examples\multi-bot\node_modules\botkit\lib\CoreBot.js:779:49)
    at C:\Users\User\Desktop\botkit-middleware-master3\examples\multi-bot\node_modules\botkit\lib\CoreBot.js:866:32
    at Object.bot.findConversation (C:\Users\User\Desktop\botkit-middleware-master3\examples\multi-bot\node_modules\botkit\lib\Facebook.js:103:13)
    at C:\Users\User\Desktop\botkit-middleware-master3\examples\multi-bot\node_modules\botkit\lib\CoreBot.js:862:21
    at next (C:\Users\User\Desktop\botkit-middleware-master3\examples\multi-bot\node_modules\ware\lib\index.js:82:27)
    at C:\Users\User\Desktop\botkit-middleware-master3\examples\multi-bot\node_modules\wrap-fn\index.js:121:18
    at C:\Users\User\Desktop\botkit-middleware-master3\examples\multi-bot\node_modules\botkit-middleware-watson\lib\middleware\index.js:121:9
    at tryCatcher (C:\Users\User\Desktop\botkit-middleware-master3\examples\multi-bot\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\util.js:16:23)
    at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (C:\Users\User\Desktop\botkit-middleware-master3\examples\multi-bot\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:512:31)
    at Promise._settlePromise (C:\Users\User\Desktop\botkit-middleware-master3\examples\multi-bot\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:569:18)
    at Promise._settlePromise0 (C:\Users\User\Desktop\botkit-middleware-master3\examples\multi-bot\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:614:10)
    at Promise._settlePromises (C:\Users\User\Desktop\botkit-middleware-master3\examples\multi-bot\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:693:18)
    at Promise._fulfill (C:\Users\User\Desktop\botkit-middleware-master3\examples\multi-bot\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:638:18)
    at Promise._resolveCallback (C:\Users\User\Desktop\botkit-middleware-master3\examples\multi-bot\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:432:57)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to debug your code, but the likely cause is that the returning response you get back is invalid, or no call was made prior to reading the response.

The error:

```
Fatal TypeError: Cannot read property 'output' of undefined
```

`output` is a JSON object that is returned in the response.

Obvious errors

- Service username/password is wrong.
- Workspace ID is wrong.
- URL was not specified if your conversation service is not in the US. Most sample code assumes it runs in the US.

Comment: so the error could happen in workspace ID, conversation_name and password? what is conversation_url? my last version of botkit didnt have this. where should i get the conversation_url from?

Comment: You get all that from the Conversation service you created.

Comment: is still odesnt works. no error message, is just stuck at

nfo: ** No persistent storage method specified! Data may be lost when process shuts down.
nfo: ** Serving webhook endpoints for Messenger Platform at: http://MY_HOST:undefined/facebook/receive

Comment: only stuck at 

{ 'hub.mode': 'subscribe',
  'hub.challenge': '1542748881',
  'hub.verify_token': 'verify_token' }

no reply